# Erro Referência indefinida ao Simbolo

Tags: c++, opencv

Bom Dia estou estudando a biblioteca Opencv para visão computacional no Ubuntu 14.04 estou utilizando o Eclipse Mars.2 programando em c++. Aparece o seguinte erro:

> ./imagem.o: referência indefinida ao símbolo
>   '_ZN2cv6imreadERKNS_6StringEi'

Meu código está abaixo

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    if( argc != 2)
    {
     cout <<" Usage: display_image Tom.jpg" << endl;
     return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! image.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", image );                   // Show our image inside it.

    waitKey(0);                                          // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Ja tentei de tudo mas não consegui nada. Não faço ideia do que está acontecendo. Grato se obter respostas

Comment: Está usando OpenCV 2.4.*? Ou OpenCV 3.*?

Comment: Esse é um erro de linkedição, certo? Supondo que sim, você verificou se o seu Makefile está incluindo as bibliotecas do OpenCV corretamente?

Comment: Ola amigo, estou utilizando a versão 3.1.0. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Realmente foi um problema inclusão das bibliotecas do opencv. Neste caso em específico foi o opencv_imgcodecs. Estou tendo dificuldades em descobrir qual delas eu devo referenciar em cada caso, mas estou estudando sobre. Se tiver um bom manual para me indicar ficarei agradecido. Muito obrigado pela dica.